# How to Convert cURL POST Request in PHP to Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, http-status-code-500

VoIP.ms offers the ability to send SMS text messages from its API. They provide the following sample code:

```
<?
$postfields = array(
    'api_username'=>'john@domain.com',
    'api_password'=>'password',
    'method'=>'getServersInfo',
    'server_pop'=>'1'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://voip.ms/api/v1/rest.php");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$data=json_decode($result,true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

When I execute the following command from the command line in Terminal, I'm able to successfully send an SMS text message from VoIP.ms:

```
curl -X POST -F 'api_username=john@domain.com' -F 'api_password=password' -F 'method=sendSMS' -F 'did=1234567890' -F 'dst=0987654321' -F 'message=Hello' https://voip.ms/api/v1/rest.php
```

By searching around on Google, I've cobbled together the following Google Apps Script:

```
function sendSMS() {
  var formData = {
    api_username : "john@domain.com",
    api_password : "password",
    method : "sendSMS",
    did : 1234567890,
    dst : 0987654321,
    message : "Hello"
};
  var options = {
    method : "POST",
    payload : formData
};
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://voip.ms/api/v1/rest.php", options);
}
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

> Exception: Request failed for https://voip.ms returned code 500. Truncated server response:  > xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">env:Bodyenv:Faultenv:Codeenv:Value... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
> sendSMS   @ Code.gs:14

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Try strings: `"1234567890",
    dst : "0987654321",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following curl command to Google Apps Script. And, your curl command works fine.

  ```
    curl -X POST -F 'api_username=john@domain.com' -F 'api_password=password' -F 'method=sendSMS' -F 'did=1234567890' -F 'dst=0987654321' -F 'message=Hello' https://voip.ms/api/v1/rest.php
  ```

#### Modification points:

- From your sample curl command, it seems that `did : 1234567890` and `dst : 0987654321` should be `did : "1234567890"` and `dst : "0987654321"`. This has already been mentioned in [the TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74293903/how-to-convert-curl-post-request-in-php-to-google-apps-script#comment131163735_74293903).
- In your curl command, `-F` is used. In this case, the content type of the request header is `multipart/form-data`. Unfortunately, UrlFetchApp uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the default content type.

When these points are reflected in tha Google Apps Script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function sendSMS() {
  var formData = {
    api_username: "john@domain.com",
    api_password: "password",
    method: "sendSMS",
    did: "1234567890",
    dst: "0987654321",
    message: "Hello"
  };
  var options = { payload: Object.entries(formData).reduce((o, [k, v]) => (o[k] = Utilities.newBlob(v), o), {}) };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://voip.ms/api/v1/rest.php", options);
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your URL of `https://voip.ms/api/v1/rest.php` can be accessed from the Google side, and the values of your `formData` are valid values. Please be careful about this.
- At UrlFetchApp, the request body of `multipart/form-data` is automatically created in the internal server side. But, if this request body couldn't be used to your API (There is sometimes a case that this request body cannot be used.), please test the request using [FetchApp (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/FetchApp).

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)